# Programmatically editing unused explorer columns

Tags: directory, explorer

I noticed explorer has many columns that are not in actual use, i.e:

[image: Columns]

I would like to add custom values to these columns programmatically.
Could this be done? How?

Answer (score 0):

The only columns I found how to edit are

```
Title
Subject
Author
Tags
Comments
```

It's done using `desktop.ini`

see `[{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}]` at [Desktop.ini documentation](http://hwiegman.home.xs4all.nl/desktopini.html).

and see [this Microsoft Answers thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-do-you-add-tags-to-file-folders/e665d43e-b0ea-455b-adca-c4f26536ac7a?page=3).